# Iterating through a list of coordinates?

Tags: python, list, random

I have two functions where the first generates a random list of coordinates. The second function, I need it to iterate through the list of coordinates and draw each coordinate. When I execute my code, I get an error and not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
import random
import turtle

def generate_map(x_range, y_range, locations):

  generated_map = []
  for x in range(locations):
    random_x_points = random.randint(-x_range,x_range)
    random_y_points = random.randint(-y_range,y_range)
    generated_map.append([random_x_points, random_y_points])
  return generated_map

copied_map = generate_map(300,300,10)
print("Map Points are:", copied_map)

def print_map(speed, color, thickness, selected_map):
  print("printing map")
  turtle.penup()
  turtle.setpos(selected_map[0][0])
  turtle.pendown()
  for x in range(len(selected_map)):
        turtle.speed(speed)
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.pensize(thickness)
        turtle.goto(selected_map[x])
  turtle.setpos(selected_map[0][0])

print_map(5,"green",5,copied_map)
```

I think the error could be because of this:

```
turtle.goto(selected_map[x])
```

it says it is not iterable but I did this before in a previous exercise and it worked perfectly so I don't know where its going wrong and what to do to fix it? This is the way to access elements in a list so I'm not sure why it isn't working unless I'm not accessing the elements from the list correctly or should I use a nested list?

Comment: You are passing a single point to `setpos()`. Try: `turtle.setpos(selected_map[0])`

Comment: YES, what was I thinking, it works now, THANK YOU  @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 0):

As @MarkMeyer highlighted, you're passing a point to `setpos()` when it needs a pair.

Your last call to `setpos` also appears to be improperly indented.  This seems to work:

```
import random
import turtle

def generate_map(x_range, y_range, locations):

  generated_map = []
  for x in range(locations):
    random_x_points = random.randint(-x_range,x_range)
    random_y_points = random.randint(-y_range,y_range)
    generated_map.append([random_x_points, random_y_points])
  return generated_map

copied_map = generate_map(300,300,10)
print("Map Points are:", copied_map)

def print_map(speed, color, thickness, selected_map):
  print("printing map")
  turtle.penup()
  turtle.setpos(selected_map[0])
  turtle.pendown()
  for x in range(len(selected_map)):
        turtle.speed(speed)
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.pensize(thickness)
        turtle.goto(selected_map[x])
        turtle.setpos(selected_map[0])

print_map(5,"green",5,copied_map)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I realised my problem as soon as it was pointed out but for some reason wasn't able to see the problem before posting the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the lines `turtle.setpos(selected_map[0][0])` which you should replace for `turtle.setpos(selected_map[0])` because you want the list (pair) [x,y] and not only the x value.

But I noticed other things that I would definitely change:

```py
        turtle.speed(speed)
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.pensize(thickness)
```

You shouldn't put this code inside the for loop but in the star of the function.
And since you're starting on the first coordinates of the array ou dont need it in the for loop.

So the final code for the `print_map` function should be something like this:

```py
def print_map(speed, color, thickness, selected_map):
    print("printing map")
    turtle.speed(speed)
    turtle.pencolor(color)
    turtle.pensize(thickness)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(selected_map[0])
    turtle.pendown()
    for x in range(1,len(selected_map)):
        turtle.goto(selected_map[x])
    turtle.setpos(selected_map[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
import random
import turtle

def generate_map(x_range, y_range, locations):

  generated_map = []
  for x in range(locations):
    random_x_points = random.randint(-x_range,x_range)
    random_y_points = random.randint(-y_range,y_range)
    generated_map.append([random_x_points, random_y_points])
  return generated_map

copied_map = generate_map(300,300,10)
print("Map Points are:", copied_map)



def print_map(speed, color, thickness, selected_map):
  print("printing map")
  turtle.penup()
  turtle.setpos(selected_map[0])
  turtle.pendown()
  for x in range(len(selected_map)):
      for i in selected_map:
        turtle.speed(speed)
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.pensize(thickness)
        turtle.goto(selected_map[x])
  turtle.setpos(selected_map[0])
```